# all instances of UIButton sometimes have grey color rather than blue

Tags: ios, uibutton

On my storyboard, I have assigned the `Global Tint Color` to be System Blue.

About 1/20 times I run my app, the items in the navigation bar are grey rather than blue upon launch, including a segmented control and left/right bar button items, all containing text. In addition, another view in my app contains a `UIButton` of type `Info Light`, and it too is grey on these occasions. All buttons remain grey, no matter when they are loaded after app launch.

I have been unable to discern any pattern as to what might cause this.

Any idea how to fix or diagnose this? Thanks

Comment: Are you setting `tintAdjustmentMode` anywhere? If it's set to `.Dimmed` then all colors become desaturated (e.g. grey). This property is also set by the system if some UI hides the screen (e.g. an alert or an action sheet). It should have the default value of `.Automatic`. -- Check what the value of the problematic button is - it should return `.Normal`.

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Issue

You have accidentally changed the color of a viewController on the storyboard in IB, or in some class of yours you changed the UIBarButtonItem, UINavigationBar, UIButton appearance behavior.

## Solution

1. Click on a specific viewController in storyboard
2. Go to Inspector Utility, Right Side
3. Click on File Inspector (1-st Tab)
4. And change the Global Tint Color as you like

If that's not the case then try setting under `didFinishLaunching` these methods, and see if those turn to blue

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Remember second method is not recommended by Apple in iOS 7, but until now I has not given any issues to me (I have also submitted apps to App Store without any problem)
[Apple Documentation iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-DontLinkElementID_2)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but the Global Tint Color is default blue. Perhaps, though, this is the setting that is somehow getting changed 1/20 times the app runs.

Comment: In iOS v7.0, all subclasses of UIView derive their behavior for tintColor from the base class. See the discussion of tintColor at the UIView level for more information.

Comment: I know I am late, I just saw this post and I wanted to improve it for other people. @mkc842 answer edited

Comment: Setting the `tintColor` using `UIAppearance` [is not supported](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-DontLinkElementID_2) and should not be done.

Comment: @fluidsonic I am currently using these tricks on appearance proxy, and no error so far. Related to **Apple Documentation**, I don't know what to say, you are right referring **Apple Guidelines**.

Comment: It's mentioned in [other locations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW8) too. Tint color is meant to be inherited by view hierarchy and the appearance proxy conflicts with this behavior. I know that it works, but that's not the intention. If everything is set up correctly, the appearance hack is not necessary.

Comment: @fluidsonic I know what you mean, but the way of integrating app is easy by defining appearance in just one line of code, instead of changing it for every ViewController, or navigationController.

Comment: @eridb just use `appDelegate.window.tintColor = XYZ`

Comment: @fluidsonic Yes but that changes all of appearances I guess. If I want to change only the UIBarButtonItem appearance. Anyway, I am updating the answer with the info of not recommended by Apple. :)

Comment: @eridb I know what you mean :) I guess Apple doesn't want that because it's a bit against the purpose of tint color. Tint colors are supposed to tell the user where they can tap so they should be consistent. If nav bar and screen content have different tint color that would be inconsistent and not good with their HIG.